# Problem In Google Colab With request and API and iOS

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-api-python-client

I wanted to write a simple API script that returns something on colab website and gets this message:
"NameError: name 'request' is not defined.

I guess I know what the problem is, but I can't do it. I have 2 accounts on my iOS. I have Python3 installed on root, but I created a virtual root and added PATH. Unfortunately, it keeps showing me this message. I will only add that I have also imported the 'request' package.

Anyone know what the problem could be?

I will just add that I am not a programmer by profession.

Comment: The package is called `requests`. And you need to install it via `pip install requests` before you can import it.

Comment: i have installed. I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I have python 3.8 + homebrew + pip installed in Admin / Usr / bin /. I am logged in to user X and after adding the PATH and creating a virtual root, it shows me in the terminal the path that python is in Admin / User / X. The Usr folder is not the same as User. The error has not gone away.

Comment: It’s possible user X does not have permission to use packages installed by admin